# Can anyone give me examples of Breeding Pits?

Tags: apocalypse-world

I'm new to this game and so far I have managed to understand most of the concepts quite clearly - but a problem I'm having is trying to come up with a good idea of what a *Breeding Pit* (as in the the type of **Landscape** threat) looks like.

Maybe it's some king of language barrier, as I'm not a native english speaker, but it seems to me that a *Breeding Pit* must breed *something* - if that's the case, wouldn't it be more apropriate if the threat is a **Brute** (the things that are bred)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find it helpful when coming up with ideas for AW to ignore what the game actually calls the threats, and just focus on their trigger. Breeding Pits *generate badness.*

A Breeding Pit can be many things, from a literal breeding pit full of rad-wolves, to an old oil refinery leeching poison into the hardhold's water reservoir. Once again, the only thing a Breeding Pit must be is a place that *generates badness.* Sometimes that badness might be cannibal mutants. Another time it's a cult den that's creating psychic backlash from the Maelstrom. Whatever your Breeding Pit happens to be, it's making something, and that something is bad.

With all that said, it's totally legit for a Threat to create other, smaller Threats. If the cannibal mutants from the Breeding Pit aren't completely disorganized, then yeah, maybe they are Brutes.